# In Pyomo, how do I modify the Variable if the value is less than 0?

Tags: optimization, pyomo, binary-variable, logical-constraints

Pyomo does not allow to use if statements that involves variables. I want to create a new dictionary, model.Excess1, which uses the values from `model.Excess` to return the original value if `model.Excess>=0` and return 0 if negative.

I tried using the Big M method, but I am not able to get the results I want.

```
model.Excess = pyo.Var(model.Years, within = pyo.Reals)
model.Excess1 = pyo.Var(model.Years, within = pyo.Reals)
model.NegZero = pyo.Var(model.Years, domain = pyo.Binary)
model.bigM = pyo.Param(initialize=1000000)

model.C16 = pyo.ConstraintList()
for year in model.Years:
        model.C16.add(expr = model.Excess[year] == model.Target[year] - model.Actual[year] )
        
        model.C16.add(expr = model.Excess1[year] <= model.NegZero[year] * model.bigM)
        model.C16.add(expr = model.Excess1[year] >= model.Excess[year])
        model.C16.add(expr = model.Excess1[year] <= model.Excess[year] - (1 -   model.NegZero[year]) * model.bigM)
```

Comment: Welcome to OR.SE. Would you elaborate more on what exactly is the conditional expression you are trying to write? (e.g. write just it as {if (x>=a) => (y>=b)} or somthing similar).

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. 
if x>=0, z=x
else: z=0

Comment: Thanks. Waht types are x and z? (positive, integer, or binary?)

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. x is a real number, z should only be a positive real number.

Comment: I suppose the variables $x, z \in \mathbb{R}^+$. Define the auxiliary binary variable $w$ and add these constraints. $\{ x-z \leq M(1-w), x- \epsilon \leq M(w), -x + z + M(w) \leq M \}$. Also, it is possible to write this by Pyomo itself. I will add it asap.

Comment: Amazing!! thank you very much for this answer! will code into Pyomo and update you also :)

Comment: Please, try to write the mentioned constraints by Pyomo. It should work. What I meant by `write this by Pyomo itself` was there is a Built-In tool in Pyomo that converts this form of disjunctions automatically.

Comment: Ohh i see. As i am pretty new at pyomo, i am not too familiar with using this. can you share a link on how to use this tool?

Comment: I will add an answer asap

Answer (score 1):

Suppose, the variables ($x$, $z$) $\in \mathbb{R}^+$. To enforce the first conditional expression, you have to define an auxiliary binary variable $w_1$ and the following constraints:

$$ x \leq Mw_1 - \epsilon \quad (1) $$
$$ x - z \geq m(1-w_1) \quad (2) $$
$$ x - z \leq M(1-w_1) \quad (3) $$

For the second conditional expression, you will need to use another auxiliary binary variable $w_2$ and enforce what you want whether it depends on the $x$ or not. Also, Pyomo has a built-in tool, *Generalized Disjunctive Programming*, which somehow makes these kinds of modeling automatically under the hood. The sample code would be:

```
import pyomo.environ as pyo
import pyomo.gdp as gdp

model = pyo.ConcreteModel()

model.x = pyo.Var(bounds=(0, 10))
model.z = pyo.Var(bounds=(0, 10))

@model.Disjunction()
def rule(model):
    disjunct_A = [
        model.x >= 0,
        model.x == model.z
    ]
    disjunct_B = [
        model.x <= 0,
        model.z == 0
    ]
    return [disjunct_A, disjunct_B]

pyo.TransformationFactory('gdp.bigm').apply_to(model)
```